# Python Invoke tasks on a pip package

Tags: fabric, pyinvoke

I'm working on a pip package for our company that we can hopefully install on your applications and have a set of [invoke](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke) task that we run use locally on our machines. So far, creating a task is really simple but I want to know if it's possible to have invoke find tasks inside installed packages?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From invoke you can certainly use the Collection class to aggregate the tasks that you find. Not so sure there is auto-detecting.

[github: invoke/collection.py](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/blob/0ad8c2b37abf57261f536444a2cd2efe1b480695/invoke/collection.py)